# how to get only one key in a HashMap with "similar" keys

Tags: java, dictionary, iteration

I have an object "ObjectName" defined by String hostName and List serviceList.

two serviceLists might contain one or more of the same string.

Each string is the name of a method. There can't be methods with same name that do different things or methods with different names that do the same things.

Each ObjectName is paired with an unique integer. Then I create a

```
Map<ObjectName, Integer> objectPorts = new HashMap<>();
```

I add to this map two nodes with a duplicate string in their serviceList

example:

objectName1's serviceList has {method1, method2, method3}, while objectName2's serviceList has {method4, method2, method5}

objectPorts contains two times the string "method2"

Now I want to search the map for "method2" and execute the code of method2. I want the execution of the code to be done only once, not for each entry of "method2".

how to do this?

I was using this code: (edit: added the switch portion for clarification)

```
public long executeMethod(String methodName, int n1, int n2) throws Exception {
  long result = 0;
  for(Map.Entry<Object, Integer> pair : something.entrySet()) {
    List<String> methods = pair.getkey().serviceList;
    if(methods.contains(methodName) {
      switch(methodName) {
      case "method1":
        result = arithmeticClient.method1(n1, n2);
        break;
      case "method2":
        result = arithmeticClient.method2(n1, n2);
        break;
      case "method3":
        result = arithmeticClient.method3(n1, n2);
        break;
      case "method4"
        result = arithmeticClient.method4(n1, n2);
        break;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

but it executes the code of methodName for each instance of methodName present in the map, so it's not what i want it to do. how can I modify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I am understanding, all you would need to do is break out of the for loop once it has executed. So something like this --

```
for(Map.Entry<Object, Integer> pair : something.entrySet()) {
    List<String> methods = pair.getkey().serviceList;
    if(methods.contains(methodName) {
      does something
      break;
    }
}
```

break is actually a java keyword that "breaks" out of the current loop you are in. So adding it after the code "does something" would mean the loop would exit and the code would only be executed the one time.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to fix this would be just to add a boolean to indicate if method 2 had been called previously during the loop:

```
public long executeMethod(String methodName, int n1, int n2) throws Exception {
  long result 0;
  boolean executed = false;
  for(Map.Entry<Object, Integer> pair : something.entrySet()) {
    List<String> methods = pair.getkey().serviceList;
     if(methods.contains(methodName) && !executed){
         //do something
         executed = true;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

This will stop method 2 or whatever from being executed more than one time if the value is contained in multiple Lists associated with the objects of your map.

Comment: occam's razor strikes again...
Thanks, that should work perfectly

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you're doing a bunch of extra looping.  Why not just break the loop once you've executed?  No need to keep checking through the loop.

Comment: Just seems like a weird data structure to me so while that should fix your problem I'd think of working out a different approach to this.

Comment: @JamesMontagne you're right this does keep looping. I just chose to use this approach instead of break because I don't know what the "do something" code is its more flexible - for example, the code inside the loop could control when executed was set. From the description it sounds as though there are multiple objects with the same method and it may not always be the right choice to break at the first time method2 is found (a hash map does not return objects in order).

Comment: actually, the "do something" part is a switch that chooses between 4 different methods and execute code of one method after a request of one of the four methods is made by an ObjectName object.

Comment: Actually, I'm looking to avoid the extra looping, maybe adding a break is a better solution in this case?

Comment: (1) It is good practice to add breaks in a switch statement anyway so that execution does not continue to the next case; (2) I was unaware that you could switch on anything other than a numerical value so I'm not sure how you're switching on a method name.

Comment: (2)Breaks after each case only allow that one case to run, but if you are still looping over all of the entries, it will still execute multiple times. The break has to be outside of the switch statement to break the for loop. (2) JDK 7 implemented switching on String... Never done it before so not sure about any gotchas, but its possible now.  :)

Comment: so I add a break statement after the } that closes the switch block and that should do the trick. Thanks to both!